# How to tell credit card's country of origin by its number?

Tags: credit-card, credit-card-track-data

I'm trying to develop an application, which would give access to different services for people from different regions of the world.

Let's say, someone enters card number 1111-1111-1111-1111 . How do I use it to tell the country of origin?

I know that this is possible, because paypal and apple do it.

Comment: There's no country information encoded in the number itself; you need access to the customer's account information to get that.  See http://adywicaksono.wordpress.com/2008/02/17/how-to-validate-credit-card-number/

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's not entirely true, see my post

Comment: http://www.binbase.com/ ,  http://dev.maxmind.com/minfraud/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, I questioned whether this information could be gleened from the credit card number alone.

Then I found it here:

<strike>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bank_Identification_Numbers</strike>

**Edit** - Don't forget about [PCI Compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_compliance) if you are taking credit card numbers for payment.

**Edit** - Apparently the previous wikipedia page has been deleted.  [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number) appears to have similar information.

Comment: Well, sure.  But couldn't I get a Visa card in the United States and use it while living abroad, or vice versa?  Sure, you can get broad provider information, but I don't see how that would be useful at all for marketing purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is true. (I've done it)  I'm interested in what the OP is trying to do with the country information.  I would imagine that IP based geolocation would suit well for detecting what country a transaction is coming from.

Comment: the link isnt available

Answer (score 37):

Use [BinList](https://www.binlist.net/). It simply tells you the country of origin by checking the first 6 digits of the card number. It has a neat Json based API as well.

Comment: BinList returns incorrect brand (Visa) and country for my MasterCard, so I would not trust it.

Comment: @P.Šileikis I agree with you. Unfortunately there is no formal API for this kind of work.

Comment: From the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_.28IIN.29 the first 6-digits (BIN number) allows to define country / ranges - Binlist ranges are :

https://github.com/binlist/data/blob/master/ranges.csv

Comment: it works for my cards (+1)

Comment: unfortunately, the site stated that they don't update their data anymore and they launched a paid version under https://iinlist.com/

Answer (score 4):

checkout https://binlist.io/ opensource and it looks like they have a maintained csv file on their github page: https://github.com/iannuttall/binlist-data